# Send Email Marked High Importance via EWS API

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, blueprism

Attempting to send an email marked as high importance via EWS API. Getting multiple compile errors and or issues stating missing assembly. Any help would be appreciated. Using the following namespaces:

- System
- System.Drawing
- System.Data
- Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
- System.Collections.Generic
- System.Web
- System.Text
- System.IO
- System.Linq

I've referenced all the MS Docs on the EWS API and aware that the importance is an enum but unsure of the class to use to set the argument;

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data?view=exchange-ews-api
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/aa564670(v=exchg.150)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.importance?view=exchange-ews-api

I've tried multiple bits of syntax e.g. email.Importance = 2 but getting enum conversion error.

Current code is as follows:

```
Success = true;
ErrorMessage = "";
try {
if (To == "" && CC == "" && BCC == "") {
    throw new Exception("Recipients was not provided");
}
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
string serviceUrl = "https://mail.mydomain.com/ews/exchange.asmx";
service.Url = new Uri(serviceUrl);

EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
email.Subject = Subject;
if (isHTML) {
    email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, Message);
} else {
    email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, Message);
}
if (isHighImportance) {
    email.Importance = new ImportantChoiceType(HIGH);
} else {
    email.Importance = new ImportantChoiceType(NORMAL);
}   
char[] splitComma =  new char[]{','};
char[] splitAsterisk =  new char[]{'*'};
char[] splitSemicolon =  new char[]{';'};
char[] splitAny =  new char[]{',',';'};

//To
foreach (String r in To.Split(splitAny, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    email.ToRecipients.Add(r.Trim());
}
//CC
foreach (String r in CC.Split(splitAny, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) 
{
    email.CcRecipients.Add(r.Trim());
}
//BCC
foreach (String r in BCC.Split(splitAny, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) 
{
    email.BccRecipients.Add(r.Trim());
}

//SaveDraft
email.Save(SearchFolderByName(service,"Drafts",mailbox));

// Add attachments
foreach (String att in Attachments.Split(splitSemicolon, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) 
{
    if (att.Contains(new string(splitAsterisk))) {
        String[] attArray = att.Split(splitAsterisk, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        FileAttachment fileatt = email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(attArray[0]);
        fileatt.IsInline = true;
        fileatt.ContentId = attArray[1];
    } else {
        email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(att);
    }
}

//Send
if (SaveSent) 
{
    email.SendAndSaveCopy(SearchFolderByName(service,"SentItems",mailbox));
} else {
    email.Send();
}
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
Success = false;
ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Importance` property in `EmailMessage` class is `Enum` so you have to use [importance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.importance?view=exchange-ews-api) enum.

```
email.Importance = Importance.High // Or Importance.Low or Importance.Normal
```

Comment: Thanks a mill, so bloody simple and the one bit of syntax I didn't try. Now to figure out how to send voting buttons using the verbstream! Cheers